# Symfony2 and Doctrine - how to insert an item from joined table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two tables, `game` and `own`. In `own`'s entity I have created `OneToMany` relationship:

```
 /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game") */ 
 private $game;
```

And in `game` Entity field `id` is also mapped:

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Own", mappedBy="game")
```

Now I have a problem with inserting new data in my database. I tried simply persisting objects:

```
$gameown = new Own();
$gameown -> setGame('3');
$gameown -> setUpdated(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($gameown);
$em->flush();
```

But it doesn't work. Symfony is saying that it must be an `Game` instance, not a string. How to solve this?

When I try this:

```
$gameown -> setGame($game->getId('3'));
```

It insert okay, but... null values.

Comment: You need to think in terms of objects, not column ids.  $gameown->setGame($game);  Where $games is an actual game entity or a partial reference.  Consider going through the doctrine 2 manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or

You can do this way as well

`$gameObject = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Game')->findOneBy(array('id' => 3));`

Then you can use

`$gameown->setGame($gameObject);`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to use a game object, and doctrine will do the work for you. 
Think with object, not with table.

First, you have to retrieve your objects (from the database for example) :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$game = $em->getRepository('AppMonBundle:Game')->find(3);
```

Then, you can set the relation :

```
$gameown->setGame($game);
```